# Can I both use ProxyPreserveHost and RequestHeader set Host in Apache VirtualHost?

Tags: apache, http-headers, virtualhost, mod-proxy, mod-headers

I am trying to set the host in the request header to "server2" for when ProxyPass directs the request to server2 but preserve the host in all other cases (when it passes it to server1).

```
<Proxy "/path1">
  RequestHeader set Host server2
</Proxy>
ProxyPass         /path1  http://server2/path1
ProxyPassReverse  /path1  http://server2/path1

ProxyPreserveHost      On
ProxyPass         /    http://server1/
```

Is there a way to have ProxyPreserveHost on Off for incoming urls starting with /path1 but have it on On for all other urls? Or change the Host in the RequestHeader as i tried in the above code sample (which didn't work).

I am using Apache version 2.2.22 on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

This is not immediately an answer to the question, but it is an answer to my problem.

I decided to try nginx instead of Apache 2.2 and with this sites-available configuration it worked:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location path1 {
    proxy_set_header Host 'server2';
    proxy_pass http://server2/path1;
  }
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://server1;
  }
}
```

I think Apache 2.4 also supports locations. So I still do not know if it is possible in Apache 2.2, but this worked for me with nginx.